# Transaction blocks from delete operation in postgresql. Logs?

Tags: sql, transactions, postgresql-9.1, delete-row

I have query that delete records from the very large table that has 30 millions records.I am deleting records in small chunks, like 10k records in one small operation.When I ran this query 5 times it worked fine.

But after that it is not coming out. Now it is not able to delete even 10 records also. I suspect may be it has generated huge transaction logs. If it is so can some body please help me with how to clear transaction logs? and if any thing that i have to change with my delete query? Any query to find out log size?I am using postgres 9.1

```
 WITH ids_to_delete  as(
     SELECT rh.dp_value_id 
     FROM raw_dp_links rh LEFT OUTER JOIN dp_values dp 
     ON  rh.dp_value_id=dp.dp_value_id 
     where   dp.dp_value_id is null
     limit 10000
    )
    delete from  raw_dp_links  where dp_value_id  in (select dp_value_id from ids_to_delete)
```

Comment: Most probably your query is waiting for a lock. See here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring If the size of WAL segments (there is no such thing as a "transaction log" in Postgres) were too big, you would get an error message

Comment: yes you are right because when i restarted my db it was working fine .But why lock is getting acquired in simple delete operation?

Comment: Your delete statement will not lock itself. You probably have other transactions that modify those rows. Or some foreign keys where the referenced table is modified. Do read the wiki page and run the statements to investigate what is causing those locks. It's impossible to tell without more information.

Comment: Ok thank you  ...you gave some direction to proceed...

Comment: Yes there is one CONSTRAINT raw_data_fk FOREIGN KEY (raw_data_id) REFERENCES raw_data (raw_data_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT. so can i delete foreign key constraint or is there any way to delete foreign key constraint temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

First, PostgreSQL transaction logs are mostly a factor when you are restoring (after a power failure or point in time recovery) or when doing replication.  Because of the way PostgreSQL handles on-disk storage, large log segments from transactions will not give you problems.  PostgreSQL uses heap tables (not ordered around indexes) with asynchronous garbage collection (autovacuum), so the only point where log segments are an issue is at transaction commit.

Much more likely are row locks from other write operations on the same table.  When this happens, PostgreSQL cannot know safely what to do until after the other transaction completes so it will wait.

Comment: Ok i think you are right ...so  i can run this first ALTER TABLE table_name  DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;  then i think it should work..

Comment: Yeah if you do that you get an exclusive lock on the table during your write and nobody else can write.